# Can I create a generic web service/dispatch method that responds to ALL requests with JAX-WS?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm trying to create a generic web service that will always respond with "OK", regardless of the request's header or body contents.  I can do this in Axis2 with a `RawXMLInOutMessageReceiver`, but I'd prefer to use JAX-WS (which I am completely new to) if at all possible.  So far I've got a simple interface:

```
@WebService
public interface DummyService {
    @WebMethod String processMessage(Object obj);
}
```

and a simple implementaion:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.dummyservice.DummyService")
public class DummyServiceImpl implements DummyService {
    @Override
    public String processMessage(Object obj) {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

I can successfully publish the service with `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint#publish(...)`, but when I hit it with a simple SOAP request, e.g.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
   <derp/>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm greeted with a SOAPFault stating `Cannot find dispatch method for {}derp`.

**Is it even possible to create a generic/dumb web service that will ACK everything with JAX-WS?  If so, could someone point me in the right direction?**

---

**EDIT**
Thanks to the tip from McDowell, I was able to do this with a `SOAPHandler`:

```
public class DummySOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(MessageContext context) {
        return process((SOAPMessageContext) context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext context) {
        return process((SOAPMessageContext) context);
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) { }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    private boolean process(SOAPMessageContext ctx) {

        try {
            SOAPMessage message = ctx.getMessage();
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
            SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();

            if ((Boolean) ctx.get (MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)) {
                Iterator<SOAPElement> bodyChildren = body.getChildElements();
                while (bodyChildren.hasNext()) {
                    SOAPElement child = bodyChildren.next();
                    child.detachNode();
                }

                body.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("OK"));
                message.saveChanges();
            }
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply create Servlet to do this? What value is the WS stack bringing you to make it worth while to jump through its hoops?

Comment: This is meant to be used to test various SOAP clients.  There is additional work to be done with regard to logging and manipulating various header elements, I've just dumbed the problem down for the sake of question clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect your service is expecting something of the form:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:dum="http://yournamespace/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <dum:processMessage>
     <!-- xsd:anyType -->
    </dum:processMessage>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Add `?WSDL` to your endpoint and inspect the operation input XML type and the namespaces.

You might be able to do something with a [logical handler](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html) ([javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/LogicalHandler.html)) to transform the incoming request to this form - I haven't tried.

Comment: Thanks McDowell, I was able to use a javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler to accomplish what I wanted by ensuring that handleFault and handleMessage always return <OK/> for outbound messages.